# How to change the current database dynamically on code igniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to change the database name before a query using codeigniter.

I read a lot of questions here that explain how to use config/database but I cant use this solution because the name of the databases stays recorded on another database.

I'm trying to do an API that check the user, then grab the database_path, then run a command at this database...

And I'm unable to solve it.

Any helps are welcome

Comment: `change the database name` means you need to have more than one database connection, right?

Comment: Yeah, but i just solved it :D

if ( isset ($data['database'] ) )
$this->db->database = $data['database'];
  
$this->db->close();
$this->db->reconnect();

I just had to close the connect then reconnect ;-; I'm feeling soo stupid